# Why is my lambda not able to identify dependencies in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda pipeline using Github Actions. Part of this pipeline includes zipping and uploading the lambda files and dependencies from my Github Actions container to AWS.

When I invoke my lambda, I experience an import error:

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'axios'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "stack": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

My lambda folder structure is correct, and it was previously able to execute successfully. I double, triple, quadruple checked my `package.json` - axios is there. I even see `node_modules/axios` in the AWS Lambda Console. I can't reproduce the bug locally.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to `chmod -R 777 .` before zipping and uploading the lambda code as part of my deployment pipeline.

I was previously `chmod -R 744 .` but that doesn't cut it.

This only became a problem when I included dependencies as part of `node_modules`.

If you know the exact `chmod` level necessary, please comment below.